# How to read multiple files stored in a given folder and fetch specific date value form all files -- Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

There are multiple  text files in a folder and the requirement is to write a python code to  read all the text files and extract date field after this bit of text "$published_date:" (For example ,published_date: January 02 2020) from each of the text files .

Files consist of several lines along with "$Publisher_Date: " printed on second line.

All files look like this :-

### $Publisher_Name: ABC Corp.
$Publisher_Date: January 02 2020.
This copy was authored by xyz.

---

Desired Output is to print all the date values (in below format) and the corresponding files in below format :-

### [image]

I am newbie in python and attempted to read files from the folder '/home/bin/' but after that not getting much clues how to extract date from a these files and convert into specific date format. Any help would be highly appreciated .

import glob
import errno

path = '/home/bin/*.txt'
files = glob.glob(path)
for name in files:
try:
with open(name) as f:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There must be a better way but there you go:

```
import os

def extract_date(file):
    content = open(file, 'r')
    for i in range(2):
        line = content.readline()
        if not line:
            return ""
    x = line.find(':')
    if x == -1:
        return ""
    date = line[x + 1:].split()
    months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
    to_return = []
    to_return.append(date[-1])
    if date[0] in months:
        month = str(months.index(date[0]) + 1)
        month = '0' + month if len(month) == 1 else month
        to_return.append(month)
    to_return.append(date[1])
    return "/".join(to_return)
    

if __name__=="__main__":
    folder = "txt/"
    _,_,filenames = next(os.walk(folder))
    dates = []
    for i in filenames:
        dates.append(i + " " + extract_date(folder + i))
```

From there you have a list containing the files and the dates that you can work with

Comment: If you only care about files ending with ".txt"
add this line: "if i.endswith(".txt"):"

Answer (score 0):

To be clear - do you just want to append the date to an edited filename?

strickly speaking this will do what I think you've asked for.
Couple of things I would actually do instead - but this is use case dependent.

extract the created/ modified date from `os.path.getctime`/ `getmtime` instead - far more stable and reliable and convert to date using `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp`.

Create a custom filename if you're literally having to extract this information from the filename itself.
e.g - append the date to the filename using underscores
`file_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(parse(date),'%Y_%m_%d')`
`file_name = name.split('/')[0] + file_date + '.txt'`

Or ask whoever is sending this data to you to amend the convention if they can.

Anyway, this works once you've got your list of files.

I've used your demo file as a starting point - and you could easily store the output as tuple, dict or list. I just chose list as it's a bit nicer to work with imo.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse


fnames = ['$Publisher_Name: ABC Corp. $Publisher_Date: January 02 2020. This copy was authored by xyz.'
          ,'$Publisher_Name: XYZ Corp. $Publisher_Date: January 06 2020. This copy was authored by xyz.']

new_fnames = []
for fname in fnames:
    blank,name,date = [i.split(': ')[-1].split('.')[0].replace(' ','/') for i in fname.split('$Publisher')]
    file_date = datetime.datetime.strftime(parse(date),'%Y/%m/%d')
    file_name = name.split('/')[0] + '.txt'
    new_fnames.append([file_name + ',' + file_date])
```

Comment: Hi Tristan , Just want to print all file name along with the date values fetched from each files .

Files       Date
----        --------
abc.txt     2020/02/01
def.txt     2020/03/02
123.txt     2020/12/23

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to extract date from your file with function like below:

```
import re    
def f(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        for s in f:
            # match text between Publisher_Date: and '.'
            m = re.search('(?<=Publisher_Date: ).[^.]*', s)
            if m:
                return(fn, m.group()) # # tuple (filename, date)
        else:
            return None # no match in file
```

Then you need to loop over files in directory, os.listdir() will help, and format your output. Regular expressions are worth investing time if you want to program.

Comment: Hi @Jacek Błocki , Thanks for your solution . Still need your help to get desired output . Would appreciate if you could please help me on it .I have added my script in the answer section ..Thanks

Comment: Which section of your script are you referring to?